# Bash swap array location

Tags: bash, indexing, swap

I need to swap the order in a string array.

Not sure can be done by using switching index method or any suggestions are welcomed.

Example:

```
    default=("apple" "banana" "mango" "orange" "peach")
```

default output will be:

```
apple
banana
mango
orange
peach
```

the output I need:

```
orange <--- switch with apple
banana
mango
apple <--- switch with orange
peach
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please include the specifics of the problem you're trying to solve (even if it is an assignment) to give enough context?

Comment: There's nothing specific to bash at all here -- you could do this the exact same way in any other language that supports mutable arrays, or just to swap values in named variables in languages that don't support arrays at all. (Some other languages might support destructuring to make the temporary storage aspect implicit, but the easy/obvious way works here as much as it works anywhere... which is why we really need a question to be explicit enough that we can tell what problem you had).

Answer (score 0):

Save `"${default[0]}"` and `"${default[3]}"` to two separate variables and update the relevant indexes with the values of those variables swapped around.

(Since this looks like an assignment and you haven't included your code I've responded with high level instructions.)

Answer (score 0):

This will save the two values in a variable and assign them to the other element of the array as somebody has stated before.

```
firstValue=${default[0]}
fourthValue=${default[3]}
default[3]=$firstValue
default[0]=$fourthValue
```